# Select all group when one condition satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A    B
0  2002-01-12   39
1  2002-01-12   17
2  2002-01-12   31
3  2002-01-15   12
4  2002-01-15   25
5  2002-01-15   25
6  2002-01-20   16
7  2002-01-20   40
8  2002-02-20   20
```

I want to select `A` groups where condition `B>30` is satisfied at any `B` value.

Output should be:

```
            A    B
0  2002-01-12   39
1  2002-01-12   17
2  2002-01-12   31
6  2002-01-20   16
7  2002-01-20   40
8  2002-02-20   20
```

I´ve tried:

```
df.groupby('A').B.ge(30)
```

Comment: You do not have `C` in your example.

Comment: The last row should not be included in the result (2002-02 != 2002-01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `any` , we using `filter` with `any`

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x : x['B'].ge(30).any())
Out[169]: 
            A   B
0  2002-01-12  39
1  2002-01-12  17
2  2002-01-12  31
6  2002-01-20  16
7  2002-01-20  40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: (x > 30).any())]
```